# How to get this "id " value from a JSON response?

Tags: android, json

> Here is my JSON response :

```
{
"Events": [
    {
        "id": 239,
        "EventTitle": "Summer Holidays",
        "EventURL": "",
        "EventURLAgency": "no",

    },
```

> How can I get the id key in a variable ?
>
> This is what I have tried so far :

```
  try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("Events");
                            JSONObject jsonObject123 = json.getJSONObject("Events");
                            String a = jsonObject123.getString("id");
                            Log.e("HOLLA", a);
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: json array then json object then value for string that is id...

Comment: try {
                                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("Events");
                                JSONObject jsonObject123 = json.getJSONObject("Events");
                                String a = jsonObject123.getString("id");
                                Log.e("HOLLA", a);
@ShivamOberoi

Comment: try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject("");
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("Events");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                String id = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

            }
        }